# Changed AF sensor and O2 Sensor but Check Engine Light still on (P0138)

Tags: corolla, o2-sensor

I recently had a CEL come up on my 2015 Corolla S CVT. It was code P0138 so with my mechanic's recommendation, I ended up changing both the AF sensor and the downstream O2 sensor with Denso OEM parts. However, the day after the change, the CEL came back on with the same error code. I have live data from BlueDriver that tells me the voltage does go above 0.9 while driving. The lambda is always around 1 however.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before? What could the problem be?